# Async method dependency

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous

I have a function that calls to an external user profile WebAPI via HttpClient asynchronously.  Base on the returned profile, the function passes some property values as parameters to a repository to get parameterized data.  The problem is the function proceeds to get the data from the repository even before the async method returns any response. I would have used a blocking sync method, but HttpClient only provides GetAsync and ReadAsStringnAsync methods.  What should I do?  Thanks.

```js
    private async Task <IQueryable<WorkItem>> GetSingleProfile(string networkName) {
      UserProfile thisProfile = await HttpClientWrapper.Get < UserProfile > (
        System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userWebApiEndpoint"], "User/networkname/" + networkName);

      IQueryable <WorkItem> userWorkItems = Enumerable.Empty<WorkItem>().AsQueryable();

      if (thisProfile != null) {
        userWorkItems = _workRepository.getWorkItem(thisProfile.userId);
      }
      return userWorkItems;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the controller code? All callers (and all its callers) of this private method should all be marked async.

Comment: Post the code for HttpClientWrapper

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is the function proceeds to get the data from the repository even before the async method returns any response.

Then `await` the task returned from `GetSingleProfile`. I assume you're currently calling it something like this:

```
...
GetSingleProfile(...);
repository.GetWhatever(...);
...
```

and it should be:

```
...
await GetSingleProfile(...);
repository.GetWhatever(...);
...
```

Note that `GetSingleProfile` should be named `GetSingleProfileAsync`, which is an indication to the users that the caller probably should `await` it.

> I would have used a blocking sync method, but HttpClient only provides GetAsync and ReadAsStringnAsync methods.

If you *want* it to be synchronous for some reason, then just use `WebClient` instead.